# What to do with this client? I'm not getting paid

Tags: payments, invoices

Is there any advice on how to get a client to submit their final payment? All the work is complete but I have been waiting for 2 months and the client is no longer responding to my messages and going to court would be a lot of work and lost time

Comment: This will depend heavily on what was agreed in the contract regarding payment terms. Can you provide a little more detail about this, as well as a summary what you have already discussed with them?

Answer (score 0):

Although it goes by different names, my first step is to send a demand for payment letter. There are numerous examples available via a quick Google search.

If that fails to illicit payment, and if the amount of money owed makes it worth it, then your next step would be to contact/hire an attorney who can advise you of your legal rights to remuneration and can assist you in getting payment.